# Is there in Google Sheets a formula to simulate the use of filter within Arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets

As far as I know, in Google Sheets `filter` function cannot be used within `arrayformula`.
I have a series of cells within the row 5 that would contain formulas with filter.
The first formula would go as follows:`=IFERROR(FILTER(Full!AA:AA,Full!AB:AB=A1),)`.

The second formula would go as follows:`=IFERROR(FILTER(Full!AA:AA,Full!AB:AB=A2),)` and so on...
The original idea was to use `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(FILTER(Full!AA:AA,Full!AB:AB=A:A),)` but it's not allowed.
Do you know of any workaround to enable filtering in several cells managing it all with one single formula?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAP or BYROW.

```
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(FILTER(Full!AA:AA,Full!AB:AB=a))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The formula you suggest should be located in cell A7 so it's giving me a Circular dependency due to the A1:A range, any solution?

Comment: can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: Solved: =MAP(1:1,LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(FILTER(Full!AA:AA,Full!AB:AB=a)))) Thanks so much